# How to reuse the observable values in CRUD methods

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In my get resquest, i need to send the set of `headerParams`, instead of calling the method to get the `headerParams` how can call and store as static value?

how to insure other method to wait until the header details available? I am doing worst practice. any one help me?

here is my service ts file:

```
    export class ForecastService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<OpenWeatherResponse> implements OnInit {
    
      private url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast';
      httpUrlGenerator: any;
      headersParams: any; //always underfed
    
      constructor(serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory, private http: HttpClient, private notificationService: NotificationsService) {
        super('Forecast', serviceElementsFactory);
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.headersParams = this.getCurrentLocation().subscribe(header => {
          this.headersParams = header; //not working. undefined
        });
      }
    
      override getAll(): Observable<OpenWeatherResponse[]> {
    
    //need to avoid it
        return this.getCurrentLocation().pipe(
          map(coords => {
            return new HttpParams()
              .set('lat', String(coords.latitude))
              .set('lon', String(coords.longitude))
              .set('units', 'metrics')
              .set('appid', '21ef99128f486ce0cb0f0612b7c2d567')
          }),
          switchMap(params => this.http.get<OpenWeatherResponse[]>(this.url, {params})),
          map((value: any) => value.list),
          mergeMap((value: OpenWeatherResponse[]) => of([...value])),
          filter((value, index) => index % 8 === 0),
          map(value => value)
        )
      }
    
      getForecast() {
//need to avoid it
        return this.getCurrentLocation()
          .pipe(
            map(coords => {
              return new HttpParams()
                .set('lat', String(coords.latitude))
                .set('lon', String(coords.longitude))
                .set('units', 'metrics')
                .set('appid', '21ef99128f486ce0cb0f0612b7c2d567')
            }),
            switchMap(params => this.http.get<OpenWeatherResponse>(this.url, {params})),
            pluck('list'),
            mergeMap(value => of(...value)),
            filter((value, index) => index % 8 === 0),
            map(value => {
              return {
                dateString: value.dt_txt,
                temp: value.main.temp
              }
            }),
            toArray(),
            share()
          )
      }
    
      getCurrentLocation() {
//looking to call as a first method and need to save in variable
        return new Observable<GeolocationCoordinates>(observer => {
          window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
              observer.next(position.coords);
              observer.complete();
            },
            err => observer.error(err)
          )
        }).pipe(
          retry(1),
          tap({
            next: () => this.notificationService.addSuccess('Got your location'),
            error: catchError((err) => {
              this.notificationService.addError('Failed to get the location');
              return throwError(() => new Error(err));
            })
          }))
      }
    
    }
```

Please check my comments for my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a shared observable and add caching using **shareReplay** to avoid calling the api each time

```
headers$ = this.getCurrentLocation().pipe(
   map(coords => {
          return new HttpParams()
            .set('lat', String(coords.latitude))
            .set('lon', String(coords.longitude))
            .set('units', 'metrics')
            .set('appid', '21ef99128f486ce0cb0f0612b7c2d567')
   }),
   shareReplay(1) // caching
)
```

and then use it that way

```
getForecast() {
   this.headers$.pipe(
     switchMap(params => this.http.get<OpenWeatherResponse>(this.url, {params})),
     pluck('list'),
     ...
   )
}
```